# JPA: TypedQuery for byte array field

Tags: java, generics, jpa

In JPA, Type of Query returns generic type object, which will needed to be casted to the specified data type. I recently saw another instance of Query which is TypedQuery. TypedQuery ensures that the `query.getSingleResult()` or `query.getResultList()` will have the specified generic type. (Eg. `TypedQuery<String>` will return object as String).

My question is what generic type will be supplied when getting result as byte array (`byte[]`)? I'm using this field to store an image.

Thanks!

Comment: ...not a [`Blob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) / [`@Lob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html)?

Comment: `byte[]` is a valid generic type, so `TypedQuery<byte[]>` will return `byte[]`. :)

Comment: @Powerlord I prefer byte[] than blob cause it's more convenient in Java. Thanks anyway for giving an alternative.

Comment: @EriezeLagera Blobs can be accessed as a `byte[]` using the @Lob annotation.  The [@Lob documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html) show an example of it.

Comment: @kocko I didn't realize that byte[] is a class. Ö `byte[].class` is present. :)) Thank you for informing me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

byte[] turns out to be also a generic type in Java. By doing so, the TypedQuery will be like this,

> `TypedQuery<byte[]> query;`

Then for the type of the *query result* will be **byte[].class**

That's it, result will be a type of byte[].